# Matlab - PCA on EEG data?

Tags: matlab, pca

I want to apply principal component analysis on my eeg data, but i'm little confused on how to do that on matlab. I have an NxM matrix, where N is the number of samples and M the number of EEG channels, and i want to end up having 1 time series with the 1st principal component.

Is this the right way?

```
[coeff, score] = pca(eeg_data);
new_data = score(:,1);
```

Thanks

Comment: Someone thinks my answer wasn't appropriate for some reason, and has deleted it, which I can't be bothered to fight about. The answer said that yes, this is the right way to do it. `new_data` will be an Nx1 time series vector, one element per sample, containing the first principal component of your data.